# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, http-error

I know out there already so many question about this,but all answers still not solve my problem, this is first time I use codeigniter, and this source from my friend and I want to run this on my computer.

I have an application that has a structure like

[image]

and in index.php

[image]

So when I try to access the first project it will direct to

[image]

And when I try to visit the link it will give me this

[image]

in config penjadwalan_genetik/config.php

[image]

and the htaccess for /penjadwalan_genetik/htaccess

[image]

first the htaccess not like that, before i change the htaccess 
"Deny from all" the i change like that picture

I run in xampp with localhost:8000, I already tried changing base_url to localhost:8000 but the result is object not found.

Answer (score 0):

open notepad and paste this code
and save it as .htaccess file
then paste it in to your project directory

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i save it to penjadwalan_genetik folder

Comment: save it in yourproject->.htacces

Comment: i have project structure like
A have B and C inside,  B for System Path, And C for Application Folder, so i change .htaccess in C.. is that wrong?

Comment: then i have to look your source..can you just email me using team viewer or something like that

Comment: sure do you have gmail?

Comment: ok ive send the corrected one please check it up i think i found the problem in there ive attach the link to download please checkit out(second link email ok)

Comment: mail subject with this
regarding to HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found on codeigniter in stack overflow
check your mail and tell me is it ok....